# Prove that there exists only one function h

Tags: calculus, analysis

Is it correct that for any continuous $g(x)$ there is exists only one $h(x)$ such that:
$$\int\limits_{0}^{h(a)} (sin(a)cos(x) + 2) \; dx = g(a)$$.

My attempts:

After some calculations we have: $2h(a) + \frac{1}{2}(cos(2(a + h(a))) - cos(a-h(a))) = g(a)$.
I consider difference between two different posible functions such that:

$2h_1(a) + \frac{1}{2}(cos(2(a + h_1(a))) - cos(a-h(a))) = g(a)$

$2h_2(a) + \frac{1}{2}(cos(2(a + h_2(a))) - cos(a-h(a))) = g(a)$

$2(h_2(a) - h_1(a)) + \frac{1}{2}(cos(2(a + h_2(a))) - cos(2(a + h_1(a))) + cos(a-h_1(a)) - cos(a-h_2(a))) = 0$.

But I'm not sure if it's correct equation.

Perhaps there is other solution.

Comment: Very likely they intend to make you use the implicit function theorem.

Comment: I think this is easier without evaluating the integral at all. What can you say about $\int_0^{h_2(a)} \cdots\, dx - \int_0^{h_1(a)} \cdots\, dx$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $F_a(t) = \int^t_0 (sin(a)cos(x) +2) dx$. Fix $a$ a real number. Now remark that $\forall t, F_a'(t) = sin(a)cos(t) +2 \ge 1$ so $F_a$ is continuous and $F_a \rightarrow \pm \infty$ when $t  \rightarrow \pm \infty$. The intermediate value theorem gives $h(a)$ s.t. $F_a(h(a)) = g(a)$.